# How add a str in for bucle

Tags: python

I have this but I want that the output were 'so' and not 'os'

```
endstring = ''
for s in range(5):
    endstring += "s\n"
    endstring += "o"
print(endstring)
```

output:

```
s
os
os
os
os
o
```

How I can do that?

(come from that the problem)

```
def create_spend_chart(cls):
    global chart2
    print("...............................................")
    print("Percentage spent by category")
    chart = ""
    for i in range(100, -1, -10):
        chart += f"{str(i)+'|'}\n"
        for o in range(int(cls.percentage_of_wd)):
            if cls.percentage_of_wd >= i:
                chart += "o"
                break
```

Comment: Move the \n to after the "o" instead of the "s", and perhaps consider merging the two statements

Comment: `endstring += 'so\n'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```py
endstring = ''
endstring1 = 's'
for s in range(5):
    endstring += "o"
    endstring += "\ns"
    if "so" in endstring:
        endstring1 += f"\nso"
print(endstring1 + "\no")
```

It checks for every "so" it adds it to a different variable and makes s at the start and o at the end!

Comment: i cant do that to my real project

Comment: @MigueldeHaroce Why's that?

Comment: because the "s" come from another bucle

Comment: and after "s" i need put more things that "o"

Comment: @MigueldeHaroce there you go I fixed it